# Is there a way to create bi-directional communication between a shell app and a webview in .NET 6 MAUI?

Tags: javascript, xamarin.forms, webview, maui, .net-6.0

Recently I've had the assignment to create a bi-directional interop bridge between a shell app and a webpage in .NET MAUI. Not finding any way to solve this I had the idea of creating it in Xamarin.Forms first seeing as MAUI is a continuation on it.

After having created this app, I've tried to convert it over to MAUI using Microsoft's instructions on the dotnet/maui github wiki.

The main problem i'm encountering right now is that I've been using extensions on Android's **WebViewRenderer**, **WebViewClient** and **Java.Lang.Object** to be able to send and receive javascript to and from the WebView.

```
public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        private const String JavascriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";

        public ExtendedWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
                ((ExtendedWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JsBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            }
        }
    }

public class JavascriptWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private readonly String _javascript;

        public JavascriptWebViewClient(String javascript)
        {
            _javascript = javascript;
        }

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
        }
    }

public class JsBridge : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        private readonly WeakReference<ExtendedWebViewRenderer> _extendedWebViewMainRenderer;

        public JsBridge(ExtendedWebViewRenderer extendedRenderer)
        {
            _extendedWebViewMainRenderer = new WeakReference<ExtendedWebViewRenderer>(extendedRenderer);
        }

        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export("invokeAction")]
        public void InvokeAction(String data)
        {
            if (_extendedWebViewMainRenderer != null && _extendedWebViewMainRenderer.TryGetTarget(out var extendedRenderer))
            {
                ((ExtendedWebView)extendedRenderer.Element).InvokeAction(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

All three of these are either not available right now, or will not be implemented in MAUI, since a lot of platform dependent code has been automated now. Which leaves me with the problem that I can't seem to figure out how to change my current code to accomplish the same thing in MAUI.

Seeing as MAUI is currently not even fully released, I was wondering if this is currently just not possible or if there is some workaround to make it possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MAUI's default `WebView` has the `Eval` and `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` functions to call JavaScript code from C#:

- `Eval` just executes the script `string` you pass in a fire-and-forget way.
- `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` needs to be awaited but also returns a `string` with a stringified result of the data that the script returned.

If you want to use callback/bridge methods to automatically receive data from the JavaScript side without any input from the C# side of the app, you will have to extend the default per-platform renderers to add that functionality. The good news is that there is an official tutorial on how to do it for Xamarin Forms at [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) which is almost straightforward to port to .NET MAUI - you only have to [change how renderers are registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-startup#register-renderers).

Comment: Right, the problem now though is that this seems to be only one way unless first firing javascript towards the webview. I also need to be able to receive data from the Webview without first having to fire javascript to it, for example, a bit of text in a textfield on the webpage to be sent to the shell app using a button on the webpage.

With the code above It would invoke the C# code when a certain event, like a button being clicked, happened in the webpage itself.

Comment: @HallowedFlux just updated the answer with more info on how to receive data from JavaScript through callback/bridge registration.

Comment: Ability to execute JS in a Maui WebView enhancement issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4215

Comment: Can you explain how to use the EvaluateJavaScriptAsync method with a Javascript that is also asynchronous. So from C# call to the WebViews JS function and then wait for the function to return.

Answer (score 8):

Calling C# from a webview is actually extremely simple. Just navigate and then intercept that in c#.

the xaml:

```
<WebView  WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="400" Navigating="WebView1_Navigating">
<WebView.Source>`enter code here`
    <HtmlWebViewSource>
        <HtmlWebViewSource.Html>
            <![CDATA[
            <HTML>
                <script>
                    function callCsharp(){
                        window.location.href = 'http://poc.MyFunction?name=john&country=DK';
                    }
                </script>
            <BODY
                <a href="http://poc.MyFunction?name=john&country=DK">A link that triggers C#</a>
                <br>
                <button onclick="callCsharp()" type="button">A button calling javascript</button>
            </BODY>
            </HTML>
            ]]>
        </HtmlWebViewSource.Html>
    </HtmlWebViewSource>
</WebView.Source>
```

The C#:

```
private async void WebView1_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    var urlParts = e.Url.Split(".");
    if (urlParts[0].ToLower().Equals("http://poc"))
    {
        var funcToCall = urlParts[1].Split("?");
        var methodName = funcToCall[0];
        var funcParams = funcToCall[1];
        Debug.WriteLine("Calling " + methodName);
        
        // prevent the navigation to complete
        e.Cancel = true;

        // TODO smart parsing and type casting of parameters and then some reflection magic
    }
}
```